# jQuery checkbox value dependent submit button action

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Hello there i have a problem. Suppose i have two type checkbox(person and company).
 If i submit form without checked any person or company checkbox then jQuery give me alert. Otherwise submit form. Here is my code given..

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#submit').click(function() {

    if( $('.com:checked').length < 1 .or $('.son:checked').length < 1 ) {
        alert('Please select at least one category');
        $('form').submit(function(){
            return false;
        });

    } else {
        $('form').unbind('submit');
    }
});
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Do you see any messages in the browser's console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably using wrong or operator `.or` should be `||` and swap the statements in condition then and else part.

```
if( $('.com:checked').length < 1 || $('.son:checked').length < 1 ) {
    alert('Please select at least one category');
} else {
    $('form').submit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#submit').click(function(e) {

e.preventDefault();

    if( $('.com:checked').length ) {
         $('form').submit();


    } else {
        alert('Please select at least one category');

    }
});
```

reference [event.preventDefault](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)
         [submit](http://api.jquery.com/submit/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#submit').click(function () {
        e.preventDefault;
        if ($('.com:checked').length && $('.son:checked').length) {
            $("form").trigger('submit');
        } else {
            $('form').unbind('submit');
        }
    });
});
```